# Can I use "array" to store the return record of SQL Select statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I created a statement in PHP as below:

```
If ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT mci FROM table1 WHERE id ='12343' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2")) {
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($col1);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    }
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

It should return 2 records. How can I store the 2 records using array? Should I use Array?

And the 2 records will be do the comparsion.

```
if ($col1 <> $par1){   <--- now it only compare the return record 1! 
......
}
```

The question is how can I compare the 2 records to the variable($par1) at the same time? If any return record is not same as the $par1, it will do something.

I NEED TO DO THAT IF THE $PAR1 IS NOT SAME AS THE RETURNED VALUE, THE PROGRAM WILL CARRY OUT A PROPER ACTION! I HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO DO THIS. MY IDEA IS IT LETS STORE THE RETURNED VALUE TO ARRAY, AND COMPARE THE $PAR1 TO THE ARRAY. CAN I DO THAT?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are you intending to do with this data? This is a pretty fundamental question to be asking.

Comment: I know, yikes, that's live data!

Answer (score 0):

you can store in an array and compare with in_array().
you can retrieve array values by using foreach()